# How to enable correct block comments in tsx files in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, tsx

I use a keyboard shortcut to comment out parts of my code with a block comment.
Unfortunately the block comment functionality in VSCode adds `/* */` inmstead of `{/* */}`.

I know from template engines like twig, that generally those behavior is possible. And correct block comments is a general must have in my opinion.

Unfortunately not with tsx in VSCode.

How can I enable the correct block comment functionality? Is there a plugin or setting I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by disabling the Plugin "Babel ES6/ES7".

Without this plugin enabled VSCode works fine adding block comments in tsx.